# Installing flash player for Firefox

Tags: software-installation, libraries, firefox, dynamic-linking, adobe-flash

I would like to install Flash player for Firefox on Linux.

I downloaded the `.tar.gz`, and there are some compiled shared libraries. I am not sure how to make them work, and I am looking for a hint.

I tried to change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the folder where those libraries are, but I had no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is your linux distribution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the libflashplayer.so file in your Mozilla plugins directory (usually `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins` or some variant thereof).

Comment: thank you, there is another library in the bundle kcm_adobe_flash_player.so
what is that?

Comment: That's for KDE4. Looks like it goes in `/usr/lib/kde4` or the like.